# Excel - Working out if time is within 7 hours from now

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope you can help.

I have some dates and I need to mark in a new column if they are within 7 hours in the future from now, but can't see how to do it. I have =now() in another field but am having trouble working out the calculation for this. I'll be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula: `=IF(AND(A1<NOW()+7/24,A1>NOW()),"Within the next 7h","Outside the next 7h!")`

Comment: great! dont forget to mark it as an answer! :-)